# Highcharts: how to show an annotation at the position where user clicked?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**EDIT:**

I am having the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/ry70zxd5/) where I can enter a custom label annotation. There is something similar in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/jh8pcxd9/1/) as well, which was developed as a plugin.

The issue which I am facing is, when clicking over the chart, the input control appears at the place where I clicked and after I enter the text and click "**add**", once label is placed over the chart, it's placed far away from the position where control was placed (it goes left and up). All this works smoothly in the plugin provided above (second code snippet) and I was trying to figure out and replicate it, but I was not able to do it right.

What I can notice in my code is, seems that positions are working well, but the issue is that if the label needs to be placed at the position (X,Y) I need this (X,Y) position to be the bottom-left point of the newly added annotation label, and by default highcharts is using this as the point at the center of the label.

Here is a [video where the difference is very clear](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cYlFXh84vM).

I believe that this part of the code is responsible for this positioning:

```
 bindings: {
    inputText: {
      className: 'highcharts-inputText-annotation',
      start: function(e) {

        const xvalueAn = e.chartX - this.chart.plotLeft;
        const yvalueAn = e.chartY - this.chart.plotTop;
        var coords = this.chart.pointer.getCoordinates(e),
          x = coords.xAxis[0].value,
          y = coords.yAxis[0].value,
          navigation = this.chart.options.navigation,
          controlPoints = [{
            positioner: function(target) {
              if (!target.graphic.placed) {
                return {
                  x: 0,
                  y: -9e7
                };
              }
              return {
                x: x -
                  this.graphic.width / 2,
                y: y -
                  this.graphic.height / 2
              };
            },
            events: {
              drag: function(e, target) {
                var xy = this.mouseMoveToTranslation(e);
                target.translate(xy.x, xy.y);
                target.annotation.labels[0].options =
                  target.options;
                target.redraw(false);
              }
            }
          }];
        var _self = this;
        var labelTextForm = document.getElementById('labelTextForm');
        var onclick = function() {
          _self.chart.addAnnotation(Highcharts.merge({
              langKey: 'label',
              labelOptions: {
                shape: 'rect'
              },
              labels: [{
                text: labelTextForm.querySelector('#labelTextInput').value,
                point: {
                  xAxis: 0,
                  yAxis: 0,
                  x: x,
                  y: y
                },
                overflow: 'none',
                crop: false,
                text: labelTextForm.querySelector('#labelTextInput').value,
                controlPoints: controlPoints
              }]
            }, navigation
            .annotationsOptions, navigation
            .bindings
            .labelAnnotation
            .annotationsOptions));
        };

        Highcharts.css(
          labelTextForm, {
            top: (e.pageY - 20) + 'px',
            left: e.pageX + 'px',
            display: 'block'
          }
        );

        var unbinder = Highcharts.addEvent(
          labelTextForm.querySelector('#labelTextButton'),
          'click',
          function() {
            onclick();

            Highcharts.css(labelTextForm, {
              display: 'none'
            });

            unbinder();
          }
        )
        return true;
      }
    },
```

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

My initial code was placed here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/ufy9ovds/7/) and the first comment helped me to fix the position of the input filed itself, but the issue for attached label not matching at the same position where input filed was placed, still remains. With the initial fix applied, I got to the code which I attached in my updated question above.

Comment: Hi @delux, Please check thise example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4j1v0kmr/. I changed `verticalAlign` option: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/annotations.labelOptions.verticalAlign and position of the `labelTextForm` (`e.pageY - half element height`). Is this solution sufficient for you?

Comment: @ppotaczek please check my updated message. The label still does not match with the position where user clicks and input appears

Comment: Hi @delux, Please check this version: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4gutxaj/ with `align: 'left'` label option.